# Is there a way to make a lambda job listen to SQS without the long polling option?

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services

I have one requirement where we have to push data into an SQS queue and a lambda job will process the data as when it is pushed to SQS.

As per documentation on the AWS blog, as of now there isn't any straightforward way to do it. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

There now seems to be a way to trigger a lambda based on SQS queue message arrival:

*[AWS Lambda Adds Amazon Simple Queue Service to Supported Event Sources](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-adds-amazon-simple-queue-service-to-supported-event-sources/)*

There are some things to consider, like you cannot use a FIFO SQS queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can't really use long polling anyway as lambda will probably timeout before that.

You could [schedule](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html) your lambda to check periodically if you have a message in your queue.

Comment: Apart from periodically looking for message in queue is there any other way?

Comment: as you saw from AWS doc there is no hook defined from lambda to SQS so preriodic checking seems like the only way. I saw some thread talking about lambda - SNS - SQS but never put in practice

Comment: Thank you Frederic.